# A device to control a small circuit with my PC

Tags: usb

I'm trying to control some simple motors from my computer via USB.  I saw somebody using something to play midi files on some floppy drives via USB.  Are there any devices made for something like this?

Comment: The guy who makes the Floppy midi tracks provides some documentation on how he does it. You can find it here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12354903/FAQ%20%28MrSolidSnake745%29.docx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look into the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) - it's a bit more generic than a device to control some simple motors, and you'll end up programming it, but there's loads of information about it and a very active user group.

Comment: +1 for the Arduino, it's pretty much the simplest way to do that, and there's a very active community (e.g. in the [Electronics Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)).